# How to map MS SQL Server onto the Entity Framework?

Tags: databaselink, databases

I created a reference using the following:

```
reference=DatabaseReference[<|
    "Backend"->"MicrosoftSQL",
    "Host"->FileNameTake[databasePath,1],
    "Port"->1433,
    "Name"->FileNameTake[databasePath,-1],
    "Username"->"xxxx",
    "Password"->"************"
|>]
```

Then I feed that reference to the `RelationalDatabase` but I get the following error:

```
schema=RelationalDatabase[reference]
```

> "This platform currently does not support SQL Database functionalities."
>
> Failure["DatabaseFailure",  Association[  "MessageTemplate" :>
>   MessageName[RelationalDatabase, "nvldplatform"],
>   "MessageParameters" -> Association[]]]

This is weird since I am able to connect to the database fine using `` DatabaseLink` ``:

```
OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)",databasePath],
"Username"->"xxxx",
"Password"->"************"]
```

Also can run all the SQL Queries via the `` DatabaseLink` `` but can't map the same database to the Entity Framework.

I suspect maybe I am not specifying the `DatabaseReference` association properly.

I am on windows 10 1903 with Mathematica 12.

Comment: Try single URL string, should look like this: `DatabaseReference["mssql://username:password@host:1433/dbname"]`, where you will need to use correct settings for `username`, `password`, `dbname` and `host`. I double-checked (on Mac for now) on a different database, that this worked for Mathematica 12.0.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I believe you are the developer for compiled SQL generated from EntityFramework. Please see my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288850/entity-framework-for-relational-databases-is-compiling-if-and-which-statemen) that you can answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not so much a solution as a description of reproduction steps... but the short version of my story was to exit *Mathematica*, relaunch and try again.

*analysis current as of Mathematica v12, *Databases* paclet v0.3.3*

There seems to problem in the way that *Databases* paclet locates a supporting file, *distribution.exe* on Windows.  Starting from a clean *Mathematica* installation, I evaluated the first expression as indicated in the posting.  I received a paclet-update message which brought down version 0.3.3 of the *Databases* paclet.  I then evaluated the second expression and received the same error as reported.

I tracked down the error message to the paclet file *Python.m*, specifically in the definition of the symbol `$PythonDistribution`.  It occurs when the support file *distribution.exe* cannot be located.

But here is the problem... if I inspect the in-memory definition of this symbol, it looks like this:

[image: in-memory definition]

Now compare this with the on-disk paclet source in `Python.m`:

[image: on-disk definition]

Note how the latter looks in the *executables* subdirectory for the EXE whereas the former does not.  The file in question does indeed appear under the *executables* subdirectory so it is no wonder that the in-memory definition fails.

It is not clear how these definitions got out of synch.

**Fix?**

I exited *Mathematica* and relaunched it.  When I evaluated the first expression, I again saw a paclet-update message.  It apparently downloaded the *Databases* paclet v0.3.3 again as no other paclets were touched.  But the second download appears to have fixed up the broken definition so that the `RelationalDatabase` expression now works as advertised.

The fact that the same paclet was downloaded twice is strange.  Perhaps it is malformed in some way?  Or perhaps it was just coincidence and the original paclet update simply did not update the in-memory definitions which would get updated on relaunch anyway.

---

**Original Response**

*When I first ran into this problem, I had noticed that the issue was loading Python so I had installed it manually and the problem went away.  I think that this fix was merely coincidence given the description of events above.  But here is the original response anyway...*

At time of writing (*Mathematica* v12, *Databases* paclet v0.3.3), the `RelationalDatabase` functionality requires a functioning Python installation.  The error message indicates that no such installation is available.

Python comes preinstalled on MacOS, but on Windows it must be installed manually.  To set up a suitable environment, follow the steps described in [Configure Python for ExternalEvaluate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html).  If you choose to use an installer from [python.org](https://www.python.org) as suggested in that article, beware that you must use [*Customize installation*](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) to install *pip* and to add Python to the system path.

Once you have [Python external evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Python.html) working, `DatabaseReference` should start working as well.

Comment: The availability of Python should not matter, since we ship a custom bundled python interpreter with Databases, which is always available. It is actually a part for the paclet, for version 12 it is a single executable located in `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "Databases", "Python"}]`. That file has been bundled by PyInstaller tool and contains python part of Databases code base plus most of the db drivers plus all necessary dependencies plus python interpreter. So the fact that there is a problem is still puzzling.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I have updated my response to include detailed reproduction steps.  Something weird is happening with the _Databases_ paclet update.  I hope the information is useful.

Comment: @WReach & @Leonid I don't know what happened but I reran the same `DatabaseReference` code today and now it is working fine. One of my computer had python distribution registered and the other one doesn't have any python at all. Both of the machines got the same failure but now without any changes to the code or the machines or the server, both are able to connect without any failure. Very mysterious! (I can't remember whether an automatic paclet update happened or not)

Comment: @WReach Well, thanks. I must be ashamed. That change in paths to distribution you noticed was introduced by me, for reasons that are perhaps not too interesting to discuss, but have to do with a problem of platform-dependent paclet updates to initially platform-independent original paclet (we ended up producing a "fat" all-platform paclet 0.3.3 just for this update, there will be no such issues for future updates to 12.1+). I couldn't reproduce the problem but I could recall that that could be the possible reason.

Comment: Identical problem and fix on Mathematica 12 on MacOs too